# VoiceOver reading twice each element - Inconsistent Behavior

Tags: ios7, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I am working on Accessibility. I am using XIB file and I enabled all the views which need to be read by voiceover.Now the issue is first cell in tableview is reading twice by the voiceover. That happens only first time. I have multiple cells in tableview. But Voiceover reading first cell that too first time. If I swipe to next cells and come to the first cell again it reads only once.

Its very Inconsistent behavior. I could not able to find out the problem. I tried by passing nil values to both accessibilityLabel and accessibilityValue of the cells. But no impact on the Issue.When I disable the accessibility from the XIB file and enable it by programmatically also, but no Use.

Any Suggestions on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You positing the UIAccessbilitypostnotification for the table with (Screenchange notification), will leads to  read twice.

Dont post screenchange notification for Table view.  UIKit will handle that by default.

Comment: Is there an equivalent to this in web?